# Controls on aspx page can't be accessed from code-behind

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i have the following problem:
i work in web application and only today. any control i put on the page, when trying to access it from behind code. it doesn't appear at all. what are the probabilities and reasons for this problem.
note:
i work from a thin client. they make some maintenance on their server today. and after that i find this problem.

the previous controls on my page can be accessed normally with out any problems.

Comment: nearly i fix part of the problem ,, i go to my aspx.designer.cs,,and i had surprised why no reference to any new control to my aspx page ,,so manually i added reference to the new control then go to the behind code ,,now i can access my controls ..thanks alot but i wanna to know why my visual studio does not make any more references ,,how to fix this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if the controls have an ID this might sound stupid but perhaps yesterday someone
created the view with a snippet label *tab *tab and forgot to add an id

Below result of label *tab *tab ..

```
 <asp:Label Text="text" runat="server" />
```

Should be

```
 <asp:Label Text="text" ID="lblInfo" runat="server" />
```

Else check the attributes of the page / controls / codebehindfile

Answer (score 3):

make sure the `CodeBehindFile` attributes are set correctly

Answer (score 2):

see if run at server attribute is properly set on new controls